# I'm trying to make an if statement with "message.guild.ID" and it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've tried everything but cannot get this to work, it's meant to only send the message in a certain discord server, but when I try out the command in a different server, it still sends the message in that server.
Also I am **Extremely** new to JS and Discord.js so if I'm making an obvious mistake please don't roast me.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'contact',
    description: `Contacts the mods`,
    execute(client, message, args, Discord){
        var server = client.guilds.cache.get(`${message.guildID}`);
        if ( (message.guild.ID) = `<MyServerID>`){
            if (!args[0]){
                message.channel.send(`What would you like to contact the mods about?`)
            }else{
                const contact = (message.content.replace(`$contact`, ``));
                    client.channels.cache.get('<ChannelId>').send(`**from **<@${message.author.id}>: ${contact}`);
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }    
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not familiar with discord, but you have a typo in line 6 — assignment operator `=` should be strict equality operator `===`. Assignment operator inside an `if` statement will always evaluate to `true` if the value being assigned is truthy.

Comment: You're using `message.guildID` and `message.guild.ID` which one is it?#

Comment: I am  using message.guild.ID

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. It is `message.guild.id` , and `message.guildID` is not a property nor a method of Message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with discord's api but I think there's something strange with the variable: "server". You declare it at the first line of your function but you don't use it.

If I understand correctly it contains message.guildID, maybe you should put it in your if statement:

-> write: if (server === `<MyServerID>`)

-> instead of: if ( (message.guild.ID) === `<MyServerID>`)

And don't forget the "===" in your if statement ;)